# How to loop through Delete one row at a time

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

I am wondering if there is a way to restructure the below SQL so that one row is deleted at a time, as opposed to performing a delete in one mass operation? The reason being is that the delete action causes a trigger on this table to execute and (in cases where a USER_ID has more than 1 row) is attempting to insert data into another table that has a datetime stamp as a key and the same time (to the millisecond) is attempting to be inserted and causing a duplicate key insert error.

```
DELETE ORDERS
FROM LINE_ORDER ORDERS
INNER JOIN LINE_ORDER_XREF B ON B.OPRID = ORDERS.USER_ID
WHERE B.USERID = 'SYSACCT'
```

The thought was that if each row is deleted separately as it's own transaction then this will make each datetime stamp unique. The number of delete operations will be low and the additional processing time is not a concern in this case. Is it possible to structure into some loop or use a cursor? The primary ID column's in `LINE_ORDER` (`USER_ID` and `USER_ROLE`) are varchar columns so I don't believe I can increment this.

```
USER_ID     USER_ROLE   DYNAMIC_SW
11000_600   E_SAML      N
11000_602   E_SAML      N
11000_602   SUPRV       N
11000_604   E_PRO       N
11000_605   E_SAML      N
```

Comment: How does the delete trigger look? Maybe just add a ms to each deleted row in the insert.

Comment: "another table that has a datetime stamp as a key" ...why on earth does it have the timestamp as a key, should surely be the real question here

Comment: @ADyson Well it has two other columns as keys, but in this case all 3 columns would have the exact same value, thus causing the duplicate key insert issue.

Comment: @Nick ok but my point was, why is the timestamp (part of) the key at all? As you are now seeing, duplicate timestamps are a perfectly normal thing to expect. What is this table, what does it record - audit information perhaps? I'd have thought it would be fine for the key to be a simple auto-increment integer...what's the need for the compound key exactly?

Comment: @JNevill Can you provide an example of how this would be structured with procedure/cursor?

Comment: you can try with '... WHERE B.USERID = 'SYSACCT' LIMIT 1'

Answer (score 0):

Well, you can use `TOP` for this purpose:

```
DELETE o
FROM (SELECT TOP (1) o.*
      FROM LINE_ORDER o INNER JOIN
           LINE_ORDER_XREF lox
           ON lox.OPRID = o.USER_ID
      WHERE lox.USERID = 'SYSACCT'
     ) o;
```

You then need to embed this in a loop to delete all the matching values.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
DECLARE @i INT=
(
    SELECT ORDERS
    FROM LINE_ORDER ORDERS
         INNER JOIN LINE_ORDER_XREF B ON B.OPRID = ORDERS.USER_ID
    WHERE B.USERID = 'SYSACCT'
);
DECLARE @count INT= 1;
WHILE(@count <= @i)
    BEGIN
        DELETE TOP (1)
        ORDERS
        FROM LINE_ORDER ORDERS
             INNER JOIN LINE_ORDER_XREF B ON B.OPRID = ORDERS.USER_ID
        WHERE B.USERID = 'SYSACCT';
        SET @count = @count + 1;
    END;
```